# Replace Tab with space in entire text file python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file which contains TAB between values and looks like this:

```
Yellow_Hat_Person    293    997    328    1031
Yellow_Hat_Person    292    998    326    1032
Yellow_Hat_Person    290    997    324    1030
Yellow_Hat_Person    288    997    321    1028
Yellow_Hat_Person    286    995    319    1026
```

I want to replace all the tabs with just a single space. so it looks like this:

```
Yellow_Hat_Person 293 997 328 1031
Yellow_Hat_Person 292 998 326 1032
Yellow_Hat_Person 290 997 324 1030
Yellow_Hat_Person 288 997 321 1028
Yellow_Hat_Person 286 995 319 1026
```

Any suggestions would be of help.

Comment: What if you have spaces in the "fields" as it were... ?

Comment: I can but i am learning python and it is a requirement of the project that there should be no tabs or whitespaces etc

Comment: Okay, where are you at for this project... have you been able to read a tab delimited file in?

Comment: Do you mean can i read this file in python? Yes i can do that. But i can't figure out how to remove the TAB yet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to replace every `'\t'` to `' '`

```
inputFile = open(“textfile.text”, “r”) 
exportFile = open(“textfile.txt”, “w”)
for line in inputFile:
   new_line = line.replace('\t', ' ')
   exportFile.write(new_line) 

inputFile.close()
exportFile.close()
```

Comment: any reason you're not using a `with` statement here for opening the files?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It copies the entire thing from input file and pastes into the output file

Comment: @Shameendra, I have updated the answer check it again

Comment: @mooga Works perfectly. Thanks a lot. However i would like to suggest putting the indent in the for loop so beginners don't make a mistake

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use correct quote chars, and don't make input & output file names very similar. Based on @mooga's answer, please use this:

```
fin = open("input.txt", "r") 
fout = open("output.txt", "w")
for line in fin:
   new_line = line.replace('\t', ' ')
   fout.write(new_line) 

fin.close()
fout.close()
```